# Draw polygon on load not working - OpenLayers

Tags: polygon, openlayers

The following code should have 3 features:

1. Draw a polygon on load
2. On draw end send coordinates
3. On modify end send coordinates

2&3 work as expected. I added the drawn polygon last, there is no error on the console, but no polygon is drawn.

Also, it has no errors building in npm.

```
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
      import View from 'ol/View.js';
      import {Draw, Modify, Snap} from 'ol/interaction.js';
      import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';
      import {OSM,TileJSON, Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source.js';
      import {Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style.js';

      import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
      import Polygon from 'ol/geom/Polygon';
    import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
    import Transform from 'ol/Proj';

      var raster = new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
      });

      var source = new VectorSource();
      var vector = new VectorLayer({
        source: source,
        style: new Style({
          fill: new Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
          }),
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: '#ffcc33',
            width: 2
          }),
          image: new CircleStyle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new Fill({
              color: '#ffcc33'
            })
          })
        })
      });
      var feature = new Feature({
        geometry: new Polygon([
            [-13041991.514129914,8126540.3085058555],
            [-13766003.046047103,7167714.225696605],
            [-12562578.472725287,6668733.305050973],
            [-11486345.114470007,7099226.648353085],
            [-11730943.60498257,8439626.376361936],
            [-13041991.514129914,8126540.3085058555]
          ])
    });
    var vectorSource= new VectorSource({
        features: [feature ]
    });

    var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
        source: vectorSource
    });

      var map = new Map({
        layers: [raster, vector],
        target: 'map',
        view: new View({
          center: [-11000000, 4600000],
          zoom: 4
        })
      });

      var modify = new Modify({source: source});
      modify.on('modifyend',function(e){
        console.log("feature id is",e.features.getArray()[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0]);
        });
      map.addInteraction(modify);
      console.log(map);
      var draw, snap; // global so we can remove them later
      var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');

      function addInteractions() {
        draw = new Draw({
          source: source,
          type: typeSelect.value
        });
        draw.on('drawend',function(e){
            console.log(e.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0]);
        })
        map.addInteraction(draw);
        snap = new Snap({source: source});
        map.addInteraction(snap);
      }

      /**
       * Handle change event.
       */
      typeSelect.onchange = function() {
        map.removeInteraction(draw);
        map.removeInteraction(snap);
        addInteractions();
      };

      addInteractions();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the polygon layer to the map. As it is, you add the raster and the empty layer that will contains the new/edited drawings, but not the source data:

```
 var map = new Map({
    layers: [raster, vector, vectorLayer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
      center: [-11000000, 4600000],
      zoom: 4
    })
  });
```

Comment: I appreciate your comment. I added vectorLayer as you said, with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues to get the polygon to display:

1. you need to add another layer of `[]` to the ring:

```
var feature = new Feature({
        geometry: new Polygon([[
            [-13041991.514129914,8126540.3085058555],
            [-13766003.046047103,7167714.225696605],
            [-12562578.472725287,6668733.305050973],
            [-11486345.114470007,7099226.648353085],
            [-11730943.60498257,8439626.376361936],
            [-13041991.514129914,8126540.3085058555]
          ]])
    });
```

2. you need to add the `vectorLayer` to the map, as @JGH indicated in his answer:

```
var map = new Map({
    layers: [raster, vector, vectorLayer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
      center: [-11000000, 4600000],
      zoom: 4
    })
  });
```